# Parsing identifiers but excluding reserved words in BOOST Spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I have a SPIRIT grammar containing:

```
small %= char_("a-z");
large %= char_("A-Z");
digit %= char_("0-9");
symbol %= char_("!#$%&*+./<=>?@\\^|~:") | char_('-');
special %= char_("(),;[]`{}");
graphic %= small | large | symbol | digit | special | char_('"') | char_('\'');

dashes %= lit("--")>>*lit("-");

varsym %= ((symbol-lit(':'))>>*symbol)-reservedop-dashes;
reservedop %= string("..") | string(":") | string("::") | string("=") | string("\\") | string("|") | string("<-") | string("->") | string("@") | string("~") | string("=>");
```

Spirit doesn't require a separate lexer and parser (See [What are the Benefits of Using a Lexer?](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/01/25/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-lexer/)), and I've followed this practice by defining the first six rules as `qi::rule<Iterator, char()>`, and the last three rules as `qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()>`.  Note that these rules therefore have no whitespace skipper.

Also, note that I'm trying to parse things as `varsym`, and not as `reservedop`.  I'm only using `reservedop` to exclude things in the varsym rule.

The exclusion of reserved words in varsym doesn't work though. `==` should be a valid `varsym` but its ignored because it begins with `=` which is a `reservedop`.

The answer to another question suggested defining something like

```
    reservedop_ %= reservedop >> !symbol
```

and then using that.  I'm not sure this works, though, and it certainly doesn't seem very elegant.

What is the right way to do this in BOOST Spirit?

Comment: In case its is not immediately obvious, this is a portion of a grammar for parsing Haskell that is a roughly literal translation of the rules in the Haskell Report.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you are confusing lexing and parsing phases.

> he exclusion of reserved words in varsym doesn't work though. == should be a valid varsym but its ignored because it begins with = which is a reservedop.

That statement doesn't make much sense with the code shown, because you never show how you use the rules:

```
 rule1 = varsym | reservedop; // would parse "==" as varsym
 rule2 = reservedop | varsym; // would parse "==" as reservedop
```

Look at

- qi::graph, qi::alpha, qi::alnum, qi::lower, qi::upper etc.

  - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char_class.html
- keyword and distinct parsers in the Spirit Repository:

  - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/index.html

If you want to work with tokens defined from 'regular expressions' as your code seems to suggest, look at using Spirit with a Lex-based tokenizer:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex.html

Comment: Thank's for your feedback.  I edited the question above to make it clearer by specifying that I'm trying to parse things as `varsym` and not trying to parse anything as `reservedop`.  However, I'm not using a separate lexer, as per this quote from the link above: "In fact, Spirit.Qi allows you to write parsers without using a lexer, while parsing the input character stream directly, and for the most part this is the way Spirit has been used since its invention."

Comment: @BenRI I agree, it's just that when you define a 'character' grammar, like this, Lex might turn out to be significantly faster, especially when doing stateful lexing. To be honest, in this case, I'd very much (a) handwrite a parser thingie (b) operate lazily indexing directly into a memory-mapped data area. This will lead to 'zero-copy' (i.e. when no access is made) operation. Can't beat the performance in that.